# Equations of circular motion

Tags: vectors, rotational-kinematics

I have studied that a finite angular displacement $\triangle \theta$ is a scalar. But, $\delta \vec \theta$ is a vector. Now, when it is a uniformly accelerated motion we are dealing with, we use equation:

$$\theta~=~\vec{\omega}_i t + \frac{1}{2} \vec{\alpha} t^2, $$

where $\vec{\theta}_0$ is initial angle and $\vec{\omega}_0$ is intial 
Now my question is, What is $\vec{\theta}$ here? Vector? If yes, then how can we get a finite value for it? (Since as it is a vector only when it is infinitesimally small.) If no, then how  is this equation valid?

Comment: The equation is not valid.

Comment: It is valid. The only question was about $\theta$

Comment: It is not valid because with rigid body dynamics you deal with a sequence of rotations via. something called generalized coordinates, and not with the componets of vectors directly.

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta \theta$ doesn't necessarily need to be a scalar. Check this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_displacement#Three_dimensions) about angular displacement in 3D. It can be denoted as a vector, having magnitude equal to the radians covered, and direction according to the [Right Hand Thumb rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_hand_thumb_rule).

Saying that, there is no difference between $\Delta\theta$ and $\delta\vec\theta$.

Maybe you regard $\Delta\theta$ as the magnitude of $\delta\vec\theta$. In that case, the $\theta$ in your equation is a shorthand for the angular displacement vector $\delta\vec\theta$.

Now to answer your second question, $\delta\vec\theta$ can be finite, because its direction is given by the *right hand thumb rule* and not the direction of the *displacement vector* of the particle, during an infinitesimal change of $d\theta$.

So if the particle rotates by, say, $\pi$ radians clockwise about an axis denoted by unit vector $\hat a$, the angular displacement is given by $$\delta\vec\theta = -\pi\hat a$$

Comment: the wiki article specifically says that it is a quantity having direction in 3D. What about 2d?
@udiboy

Comment: If the circular motion is happening in a 2D plane, the vector is directed *out* from the plane or *into* the plane depending upon the sense. Either way it is parallel to the axis, because $\delta\vec\theta$ is defined as $\vec r X \vec v$

Comment: that is fine, but do you mean to say that even the finite $\triangle \theta$ has a direction? Is it a vector then? If not, do you mean to say that its a tensor?

Comment: That's exactly what I say. Finite $\Delta \theta$ has a direction.